# `FunctionDomain` working with real part

Tags: functions, complex

Is there any reason why Mathematica evaluates the following

```
FunctionDomain[Re[((I + 1) x)], x]
(* False *)
```

as `False`, where I'd expect `True`, since the function is defined for all real x?

Comment: Looks like a bug. Here's a workaround: `FunctionDomain[Re[(I + 1) x] // ComplexExpand, x]`

Comment: Yes, I thought about that, thanks @J.M.
It's interesting that `FunctionDomain[Re[((I + 0.) x)], x]` still gives `False` while `FunctionDomain[Re[( I  x)], x]` gives `True`. Also `FunctionDomain[Re[((I + 1) x)]^2 + Im[((I + 1) x)]^2, x]` gives `False` while `FunctionDomain[Abs[((I + 1) x)]^2, x]` gives `True`